# Error when deploying Primefaces app to tomcat

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, tomcat7

we have a problem deploying a Primefaces JSF application to a Tomcat from eclipse.

The used libs are:

- tomcat 7
- eclipse 4.3
- mojarra 2.2
- primefaces 4.0
- eclipselink 2.5

After starting the server we are getting the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/context/PartialViewContextFactory
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4961)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5455)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/context/PartialViewContextFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:926)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:297)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1617)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:591)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinder.java:482)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.access$400(FactoryFinder.java:138)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:989)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:316)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:303)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:219)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:360)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225)
    ... 10 more
```

This error occured right after adding the primefaces library to the project. Does anybody know this problem with primefaces?

Comment: The jsf-api jar is not being properly deployed.